# System hangs after /sbin/init starts; no login prompt

Tags: 12.04, upstart, debian

I have an Arndale board running Ubuntu 12.04 with the root file system mounted on a MicroSD card. Recent, that card was damaged and I tried to recreate the file system on a new 16GB card. All went well until I tried to boot the system; no login prompt is shown and the system seems to hang. Below is the kernel output up to the point of hanging:

```
[    3.467265] Waiting for root device /dev/mmcblk1p3...
[    3.471700] mfc-power-domain: Power-off latency exceeded, new value 4580583 ns
[    3.479390] mmc_host mmc0: Bus speed (slot 0) = 50000000Hz (slot req 52000000Hz, actual 50000000HZ div = 0)
[    3.488621] gsc-power-domain: Power-off latency exceeded, new value 9371500 ns
[    3.496328] mmc_host mmc0: Bus speed (slot 0) = 100000000Hz (slot req 52000000Hz, actual 50000000HZ div = 1)
[    3.505721] mmc0: new DDR MMC card at address 0001
[    3.510666] mmcblk0: mmc0:0001 M4G1FA 3.72 GiB 
[    3.514953] mmcblk0boot0: mmc0:0001 M4G1FA partition 1 1.00 MiB
[    3.520889] mmcblk0boot1: mmc0:0001 M4G1FA partition 2 1.00 MiB
[    3.526777] mmcblk0rpmb: mmc0:0001 M4G1FA partition 3 128 KiB
[    3.533994]  mmcblk0: p1 p2 p3 p4
[    3.537680] exynos-hdmi 14530000.hdmi: Failed to get supply 'vdd': -517
[    3.542832] [drm:hdmi_resources_init] *ERROR* failed to get regulators
[    3.549340] [drm:hdmi_probe] *ERROR* hdmi_resources_init failed
[    3.555251] platform 14530000.hdmi: Driver exynos-hdmi requests probe deferral
[    3.562880] usb 3-3: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=3503
[    3.569140] usb 3-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    3.577108] hub 3-3:1.0: USB hub found
[    3.581016] hub 3-3:1.0: 3 ports detected
[    3.587086] exynos-hdmi 14530000.hdmi: Failed to get supply 'vdd': -517
[    3.592236] [drm:hdmi_resources_init] *ERROR* failed to get regulators
[    3.598744] [drm:hdmi_probe] *ERROR* hdmi_resources_init failed
[    3.604662] platform 14530000.hdmi: Driver exynos-hdmi requests probe deferral
[    3.637751] mmc_host mmc1: Bus speed (slot 0) = 50000000Hz (slot req 50000000Hz, actual 50000000HZ div = 0)
[    3.646061] mmc1: new high speed SDHC card at address 0001
[    3.651750] mmcblk1: mmc1:0001 00000 14.6 GiB 
[    3.656879]  mmcblk1: p1 p2 p3 p4
[    3.660026] exynos-hdmi 14530000.hdmi: Failed to get supply 'vdd': -517
[    3.665816] [drm:hdmi_resources_init] *ERROR* failed to get regulators
[    3.672321] [drm:hdmi_probe] *ERROR* hdmi_resources_init failed
[    3.678235] platform 14530000.hdmi: Driver exynos-hdmi requests probe deferral
[    3.689387] EXT3-fs (mmcblk1p3): error: couldn't mount because of unsupported optional features (240)
[    3.697647] EXT2-fs (mmcblk1p3): error: couldn't mount because of unsupported optional features (244)
[    3.869477] usb 3-3.2: new high-speed USB device number 3 using exynos-ehci
[    3.901303] random: nonblocking pool is initialized
[    3.981359] usb 3-3.2: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0610
[    3.986771] usb 3-3.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[    3.994060] usb 3-3.2: Product: USB2.0 Hub
[    3.998868] hub 3-3.2:1.0: USB hub found
[    4.002356] hub 3-3.2:1.0: 4 ports detected
[    4.008996] exynos-hdmi 14530000.hdmi: Failed to get supply 'vdd': -517
[    4.014147] [drm:hdmi_resources_init] *ERROR* failed to get regulators
[    4.020653] [drm:hdmi_probe] *ERROR* hdmi_resources_init failed
[    4.026571] platform 14530000.hdmi: Driver exynos-hdmi requests probe deferral
[    4.274731] usb 3-3.2.4: new high-speed USB device number 4 using exynos-ehci
[    4.370607] usb 3-3.2.4: New USB device found, idVendor=0b95, idProduct=772a
[    4.376189] usb 3-3.2.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    4.383652] usb 3-3.2.4: Product: AX88772 
[    4.387735] usb 3-3.2.4: Manufacturer: ASIX Elec. Corp.
[    4.392941] usb 3-3.2.4: SerialNumber: 000001
[    4.398635] asix 3-3.2.4:1.0 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): invalid hw address, using random
[    4.476162] EXT4-fs (mmcblk1p3): recovery complete
[    4.491031] EXT4-fs (mmcblk1p3): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    4.497666] VFS: Mounted root (ext4 filesystem) on device 179:35.
[    4.504378] devtmpfs: mounted
[    4.506917] Freeing unused kernel memory: 484K (c08b7000 - c0930000)
[    4.679114] init: Failed to create pty - disabling logging for job
[    4.683917] init: Temporary process spawn error: No space left on device
[    4.705360] init: Failed to create pty - disabling logging for job
[    4.710438] init: Temporary process spawn error: No space left on device
[    4.729208] init: Failed to create pty - disabling logging for job
[    4.734041] init: Temporary process spawn error: No space left on device
[    4.741889] init: Failed to create pty - disabling logging for job
[    4.747787] init: Temporary process spawn error: No space left on device
[    4.836518] init: ureadahead main process (1538) terminated with status 5
[    4.959358] init: Failed to create pty - disabling logging for job
[    4.965013] init: Temporary process spawn error: No space left on device
[    4.980936] init: Failed to create pty - disabling logging for job
[    4.985899] init: Temporary process spawn error: No space left on device
[    5.023813] init: Failed to create pty - disabling logging for job
[    5.029762] init: Temporary process spawn error: No space left on device
[    5.195212] asix 3-3.2.4:1.0 eth0: register 'asix' at usb-12110000.usb-3.2.4, ASIX AX88772 USB 2.0 Ethernet, c6:8a:71:76:dc:77
```

Nothing seems to come up when i tried to Google this error; there isn't so much as an explanation what it meant by "no space left on device", as there's plenty of space left on the device.

I tried using a debian system created using `debootstrap` on Wheezy for ARM, but it was much the same behaviour. What is going on?

Thanks

The boot argument to the kernel is as follow:

```
 console=ttySAC2,115200n8 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk1p3 rootwait rw debug loglevel=7 init=/sbin/init 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue, but I got it resolved by removing `/var/dmesg*` log files.
Mount your MicroSD card on another system and remove `dmesg` logs, including `dmesg.gz`.